# Getting a table inside a class using IE object in MS Acccess VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using Access VBA I know that we can get the table object by doing something like :

```
Set objTables = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")
```

However, I wanted to know if there is a way to get tables only if it is inside  a certain class

Answer (score 0):

Yes with `querySelector(table.tableClass)`

see this linke: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp